# Change RDL version for RDLC Reports in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc, reportviewer, visual-studio-2017, rdl

I have a project in Visual Studio 2017 with .NET Framework 4. For reports I use the RDLC designer, but I have a problem. The designer creates the reports using RDL 2016 and I need you to use the 2010 definition.

Can I configure this?

I need it since the program has to be compatible with Windows XP and there is no ReportViewer Runtime that supports RDL 2016 for Windows XP.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue.  I have a similar problem.

Comment: No, now i use Visual Studio 2013 for this project.

Comment: We have a similar problem, in that we can't use the newest Report Viewer because of incompatibility with jQuery UI Tabs. We're looking at downgrading as well, since we can't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, but if a did a new report it was all right, the new report was created and saved with the old schema:
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition". (report viewed with a text editor)

When I added a parameters and re-saved, VS turned the schema in 
new schema:
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition"

But I found a solution that work also with Windows XP:

I install all necessary to manipulate the report with VS 2017 (in Visual studio 2017 are all external plug-in), then change the reference of my project e take 2 new referenze to this DLL:

1)

..\project\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.140.340.80\lib\net40\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll

2)

..\project\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.140.340.80\lib\net40\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll

After that all work.

This new version of DLL handle both "old schema" and "new schema"

Comment: Thanks, you've saved my day. as a note you need to update some values in the web.config and in your report page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This is the only way that I found when trying to use WinForms Report Viewer with VS2017 when targeting .net 4.0. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

You can check ReportViewer version and installed in your Visual Studio 2017 using PM>
(Before doing this you have to delete previous Report viewer references )
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/140.1.291.2731477-rc

This package Manager work for me.
PM>Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms -Version 140.1.291.2731477-rc

Comment: My mvc project was created in Visual Studio 13. Now I am working on this project in VS 2019. My rdlc report was not showing. After install this package, it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Reporting solutions in VS have always been tied to the version of SSDT that is current at the time of release. e.g. VS 2015 only supported the Sql Server 2016 report schema.

I think the answer is that you might be able to do something to change the schema it uses by editing the XML directly, as suggested by Ricky A, but for proper, designer support this isn't going to work.

Article from Microsoft on schema versions supported here doesn't mention anything other than schema v2016 support in VS 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/plan-for-report-design-and-report-deployment-reporting-services

I am fairly sure that your VS licence will cover old versions, and different versions live happily side by side, so install whichever other version you need for the reporting project you are editing (along with the correct version of SSDT/BIDS etc).

Answer (score 2):

Although too late, but I have fixed this issue by installing this package :

[Microsoft RDLC Report Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001)

Answer (score 1):

Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms -Version 140.1.291.2731477-rc this saved my ass